# Permission denied error for ORL data base folder

Tags: python

I want to run code over ORL database for face recognition experiment. I am using follow code to load data from 1st folder but it return permission denied error. It seems that there are too many question with this title `[Errno 13] Permission denied` but no one provide a concrete solution.

```
import cv2
path='Data_Set/ORL/s1'
face_set=[]
with open(path, 'rb') as pt:
    for i in pt:
        face_set.append(cv2.imread(i))
```

This is the error massage:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Data_Set/ORL/s1'
```

I appreciate if any provide a solution.

Comment: Make sure the file in `path` is not open for edit on your computer. If so, close the file first and run the code again.

Comment: Echoing the above. Almost certainly you have the file open

Comment: Thank you for comment, but i am sure nothing is open. the file format is pgm.

Comment: Are you running on linux? if so, did you try it with sudo?

Comment: no, i am working with windows 10 and python 3

Comment: Are you able to open the file with admin privileges? If so, run the script as admin.

Comment: @user8212173 thank you for comment, there is no issue with admin right. even i change folder access configuration but again it didn't work. i think ORL folder has some issue.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the problem with `with open()` but when I replaced it with a `for-loop` and used "os" lib instead of open build-in , I could load the data.

```
import cv2
import os
path='Data_Set/ORL'
face=[]
label=[]
for fl in os.listdir(path):
    for img in os.listdir(path+'/'+fl):
        face.append(cv2.imread(path+'/'+fl+'/'+img))
        label.append(fl)
```